# Number rings and (round) parentheses versus (square) brackets

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation, field-theory, extension-field

Is there a reason for the difference in the use of parentheses *versus* brackets as used in algebraic extensions. For example, when the field rational numbers ${\mathbb{Q}}$ extended with $i = \sqrt{-1}$ is denoted ${\mathbb{Q}}(i)$, whereas the ring of integers ${\mathbb{Z}}$ extended with $i$ is denoted ${\mathbb{Z}}[i]$?

In particular, does this difference in notation in itself carry any meaning beyond the applications to rings *versus* fields, for example? Could, for example, '${\mathbb{Q}}[i]$' and '${\mathbb{Z}}(i)$' (or similar) have useful, but different, meanings?

Brackets are also used in the context of rings of polynomials (such as ${\mathbb{Z}}[X]$, ${\mathbb{Q}}[X]$ and ${\mathbb{R}}[X]$, *etc*.). Is this related?

Thanks.

Comment: Roughly speaking, square brackets = "everything you can get by addition, scaling and multiplication", while round brackets = "everything you can get by addition, scaling, multiplication and division". So the latter are being used for fields mostly. There are exceptions, like the notation $A\left(\left(u\right)\right)$ for formal Laurent power series in $u$ over $A$.

Comment: Indeed, @darijgrinberg, one of my instructors in college made a big deal of the fact that $\mathbb Q(i)=\mathbb Q[i]$.